# Printing out Python list

Tags: python, list

```
drinks = ['cola', 'water', 'beer', 'wine']

drinks = raw_input ("What did you drink? " + print drinks)
```

So, basically I want the program to show user the question and after that print out the possible answers. The user should type one of them back into the program. I tried the code like above but it doesn't work. Printing `drinks` before `raw_input` kinda doesn't make sense. I guess you could also go with it like that:

```
drinks = ['cola', 'water', 'beer', 'wine']

drinks1 = raw_input("Hai, wanna have a look at the most popular drinks here?")
if drinks1 == "yes":
print drinks

drinks2 = raw_input("So, what did you drink?")
```

…but is there any simpler to do lists like that in Python, that user would choose from?

Thanks in advance for answer.

Comment: The code looks fine as-is. The only thing missing is the indentation before `print drinks`. Remember that python is whitespace sensitive.

Comment: In the first version, replace `print drinks` with `str(drinks)` or `repr(drinks)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution could be

```
drinks = ['cola', 'water', 'beer', 'wine']

drink = raw_input ("What did you drink? %s" % ', '.join(drinks))

if drink in drinks:
    print('you chose ' + drink)
else:
    print('invalid choice')
```

Use `join` to make a string out of the list.

Comment: Why not `print("that wasn't a choice")`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generic program by using `strip` and `lower` functions. Everything else looks okay.

```
drinks = ['cola', 'water', 'beer', 'wine']

user_input = raw_input("Hai, wanna have a look at the most popular drinks here?")

if user_input.strip().lower() == "yes":
   print drinks

drinks2 = raw_input("So, what did you drink?")
```